# Finding intersection point between two arcs?

Tags: python-2.7, shapely

I am trying to find the intersection between two arcs. I have done this for line segments using shapely package. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are the arc geometries are defined in your dataset. Generally the arc geometries are defined differently in respective GIS formats.

If the arcs are defined as tiny segments of linear objects, shapely should handle this. 
If the arcs are defined using angle and radius then it needs to be simplified into tiny linear objects and pass into shapely.

Other option is to import into postGIS database which should be able to handle any type of arc geometries and perform spatial query.